# How do I make a cell return a value based on the characters

Tags: if-statement, formulas

I have a cell that I want to use and IF statement to tell return information based on characters in the cell. I.E the cell has =M=WRFY, I want the statement to give me a start time based on the day within. I used this formula for the first set and it worked but for the next day it fails.

```
=IF(LEFT(I44,1)="S",H44,"")
```

I've tried entering the 2 where the 1 is to make it look at character 2 but its not working. Help!!

Comment: What does the formula return for =LEFT(I44,1)?

Comment: What software are you exactly talking about? Hover over the `formulas` tag and read the description: "Use only if there is no more specific tag such as [excel-formula] or [lotus-formula]"

Comment: I am using excel, I added an image of what I'm trying to do. So I have each day of the week lined out and the column with ==TWRFY represent a pattern. I want a formula in the the Sun Start column that will reference the start time only if there is an S in the pattern. Same for Mon, Tues, an so on. Hope that makes sense.